# SQLAlchemy Where Value in List of Columns

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Before moving my code to SQLAlchemy, I have a MySQL query that looks for a value in multiple columns (ex - `WHERE 'value' in (col1, col2)`) which works fine when submitting the query manually to the database.

The use case above is relatively simple, but in the future I may want to run a similar query on more than two columns so just want to get ahead of this problem now.

Currently I have converted my query to the below (which works), but I am trying to find a similar syntax to the one above.

```
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(mydb, reflect=True)
select_stmt = (tbl_pbp.select(
              ((tbl_pbp.c.home_team == team_abbreviation) | (tbl_pbp.c.away_team == team_abbreviation))
              & (tbl_pbp.c.is_corsi == True)))
```

When I try the below, I get a syntax error so not sure if it is an issue with the `in_` keyword I am trying to use.

```
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(mydb, reflect=True)
select_stmt = (tbl_pbp.select(
              (team_abbreviation in_(tbl_pbp.c.home_team, tbl_pbp.c.away_team)
              & (tbl_pbp.c.is_corsi == True)))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: It would be appropriate to include the full traceback of the syntax error as your example isn't a MCVE so hard to reproduce the exception.

Comment: That said, I believe `in_` is a method of a column, and it would be passed a collection of values. E.g. `stmt.where(column.in_([1, 2, 3]))`. So this: `team_abbreviation in_(tbl_pbp.c.home_team, tbl_pbp.c.away_team)` doesn't look right.

Comment: If you want to check where one of multiple columns is equal to a value, then an `or_` would be more appropriate there. I.e. `or_(tbl_pbp.c.home_team == team_abbreviation, tbl_pbp.c.away_team == team_abbreviation)`. If you needed to test against a variable, or large number of columns, you'd just build the comparisons using a list comp and unpack into the `or_` func. E.g. `or_(*[col == val for col in columns])`.

Comment: Your last comment is exactly what I was looking for and I can't believe I didn't think of it before - I'll give it a shot today. Just out of curiosity, what does the `*` before the list unpacking do? I don't think I've seen that syntax before.

Comment: That _is_ the unpacking. It passes the contents of the list into the function as individual positional arguments. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 2):

In order to operate on a Python value as an SQL literal in [SQL Expression Language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) it must be wrapped with [`literal()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal). The resulting construct can then be used to produce the desired `IN` clause:

```
literal(team_abbreviation).in_([tbl_pbp.c.home_team, tbl_pbp.c.away_team])
```

This is equivalent to producing a bunch of equality checks combined with `OR`, as is noted in the comments. The sole argument to [`in_()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_) should be a suitable sequence, such as a list, in this case.

Note that `in_` here is a *method* of the SQLAlchemy construct, not the Python operator `in`, which cannot be overloaded to produce custom constructs due to how it treats the return value of [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__): it implicitly converts to a `bool`:

```
In [1]: class X:
   ...:     def __contains__(self, item):
   ...:         return 'nope'
   ...:     

In [2]: 1 in X()
Out[2]: True
```